# How to disable main menu using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have menus in 'ul, li' how can I disable the parent menu using JavaScript?  I want to stop redirect for parent menu and only child menu will get redirected

I cannot add class or id in the html to disable the parent menu. is there any way that will help to stop redirect using JavaScript?

Following is my HTML code:

```
<ul class="firstLevel" style="">
  <li class="sel">
    <div class="item">
      <a title="Home" href="#/"><span>Home</span></a>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="dir">
    <div class="item">
      <a title="About Us" href="#/page-18080"><span>About Us</span></a>
      <ul class="secondLevel">
        <li class=" ">
          <div class="item">
            <a title="Vision" href="#/page-18126"><span>Vision</span></a>
          </div>
        </li>

        <li class=" ">
          <div class="item">
            <a title="Our Team" href="#/Our-Team"><span>Our Team</span></a>
          </div>
        </li>

        <li class=" ">
          <div class="item">
            <a title="Our Board" href="#/page-18128"><span>Our Board</span></a>
          </div>
        </li>

        <li class=" ">
          <div class="item">
            <a title="Our Charter" href="#/page-18127"><span>Our Charter</span></a>
          </div>
        </li>

      </ul>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="dir">
    <div class="item">
      <a title="Events" href="#/events"><span>Events</span></a>
      <ul class="secondLevel">
        <li class=" ">
          <div class="item">
            <a title="About the event" href="#/page-18147"><span>About the event</span></a>
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: cud u xplain what exactly to disable?

Comment: I want to disable main menus and only sub menu can redirect the page

Comment: based on what i understood I have disabled all firstLevel only elements but not ones under second level. have a look at my answer.

Comment: Can you add your JS code also so that the people who wants to help need  not start from scratch.

Comment: @user6617474 did my soln work?

Answer (score 0):

https://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/

```
$(child).on("click", function(event) {
  // TODO

  event.stopPropagation();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on what I understood, you want to disable all `firstLevel` links except links also under `secondLevel`. As requested I have not touched the HTML and the javascript will do all the work by itself.

*SEE COMMENTS FOR STEP-BY-STEP EXPLANATION:*

```
$(function() {
  $(".firstLevel").find('a').each(function() {
    // this is all link elements under element with class firstlevel 
    if ($(this).parents('.secondLevel').length) {
      // this is all link elements which also is under element with class secondLevel
      $(this).click(function() {
        //don't disturb the event here. feel free to remove the below alert as well.
        alert("this link will work");
      });
    } else {
      // this is all link elements under a firstLevel element but not a secondLevel element
      $(this).click(function() {
        // we shud block this click. we will return false so that jQuery will internally call e.stopPropogation() and e.preventDefault() and thus stop the link from working.
        alert("this link will not work");
        return false;
      });
    }
  });
});
```

**WORKING SNIPPET EXAMPLE:** (note that the HTML is same as you posted. no changes were made there, only the above javscript was added!)

```js
$(function() {
  $(".firstLevel").find('a').each(function() {
    if ($(this).parents('.secondLevel').length) {
      $(this).click(function() {
        alert("this link will work");
      });
    } else {
      $(this).click(function() {
        alert("this link will not work");
        return false; //this will call e.stopPropogation() and e.preventDefault() and thus stop the link from working.
      });
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="firstLevel" style="">
  <li class="sel">
    <div class="item">
      <a title="Home" href="#/"><span>Home</span></a>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="dir">
    <div class="item">
      <a title="About Us" href="#/page-18080"><span>About Us</span></a>
      <ul class="secondLevel">
        <li class=" ">
          <div class="item">
            <a title="Vision" href="#/page-18126"><span>Vision</span></a>
          </div>
        </li>

        <li class=" ">
          <div class="item">
            <a title="Our Team" href="#/Our-Team"><span>Our Team</span></a>
          </div>
        </li>

        <li class=" ">
          <div class="item">
            <a title="Our Board" href="#/page-18128"><span>Our Board</span></a>
          </div>
        </li>

        <li class=" ">
          <div class="item">
            <a title="Our Charter" href="#/page-18127"><span>Our Charter</span></a>
          </div>
        </li>

      </ul>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="dir">
    <div class="item">
      <a title="Events" href="#/events"><span>Events</span></a>
      <ul class="secondLevel">
        <li class=" ">
          <div class="item">
            <a title="About the event" href="#/page-18147"><span>About the event</span></a>
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```